# Plotting a regression plot with a conditional Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, math, regression, scatter

```
sns.regplot(x='rows', y='credit_scores', data=df1)
```

I have got this code currently in order to plot a regression line with my data where the Y axis 'credit_scores' ranges from 0 - 250. However, 4 of my plots are outliers which I do not want  included on this plot. These outliers start from 75 on the Y axis. Therefore, is there any way for me to set a condition where the Y axis only selects all the data values which are below 75?

Is there also a way where I can change the colours of my regression line so that it is a different colour from my current plots which are in blue. So maybe have my plots in blue and the regression line in red.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df1 = df1[df1['credit_scores'] < 75]
sns.regplot(x='rows', y='credit_scores', data= new_df1 , color="red")
```

This code should do your work.
Check:

[Selecting rows based on conditions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions/)

[Regplot Documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html)